# I am having problems authenticating with Kinetica's endpoint using the username and password for the REST endpoint

Tags: kinetica

Passing in `username` and `password` in the headers does not appear to work. Neither does wrapping it in json. I am getting a 500 not authorized error.

Answer (score 1):

To authenticate properly, you must send a BasicAuth request. Here is an example for python:

`requests.post('http://127.0.0.1:8888/show/table', auth=('user', 'pass'))`

[Kinetica Rest API documentation](https://www.kinetica.com/docs/api/rest/index.html)